# using entry from a class in another classes function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

the variable function is given via the class functionframe. When trying to use it in add_function i get this error.

> AttributeError: class FunctionFrame has no attribute 'function'

```
class FunctionFrame(Frame):
    """a simple application to allow a user ti enter an
    expressio
    n and evaluate it
    """
    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        a a=simple expression evaluator
        """
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bg='#A5A5A5', pady=3)
        Label(self, text='Function in x: ', bg='#A5A5A5').pack(side=LEFT)
        function = Entry(self, width=35).pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)
        Button(self, text='Select', command=self.select).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=4)
        colour = Entry(self, width=15).pack(side=RIGHT)
        Label(self, text='Function Colour: ', bg='#A5A5A5').pack(side=RIGHT, padx=2)

    def select(self):
        (rgb, hx)= askcolor()

class ButtonFrame(Frame):
    """a simple application to allow a user ti enter an
    expression and evaluate it
    """
    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        a a=simple expression evaluator
        """
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='#CECEF6')
        Button(self, text='Add Function', command=self.add_function).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text='Redraw All', command=self.redraw_all).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text='Remove Last Function', command=self.remove_last).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text='Remove All Functions', command=self.remove_all).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text='Exit', command=self.exit_app).pack(side=LEFT)


    def add_function(self):
        make_function(FunctionFrame.function)
```

Comment: 'function' as an attribute/variable name seems like a dangerous choice in any language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function` is defined as a local variable inside `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    function = Entry(self, width=35).pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)
```

To use `function` outside of `__init__`, you'll need to make this an instance attribute instead:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.function = Entry(self, width=35).pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)
```

Then, in `ButtonFrame`, you'll need to make an *instance* of `FunctionFrame`:

```
def add_function(self):
    make_function(FunctionFrame(self).function)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *set* `function` on the instance:

```
self.function = Entry(self, width=35).pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)
```

Without the `self.`, `function` is just a local name in your `__init__` method, and is discarded when that method completes.

You probably want to do the same thing with `colour`.

Answer (score 1):

FunctionFrame.function isn't defined in your code.

Quick fix is:

```
class FunctionFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.function = Entry(self, width=35).pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)
        ...



class ButtonFrame(Frame):
    ...
    def add_function(self):
        make_function(FunctionFrame(self.master).function)
```

Not sure how would you access to master attribute of Frame